# Phone doesn't charge via USB while on

Tags: usb, charging, nexus-6

I'm trying to figure out a charging issue with my Nexus 6 (Marshmallow 6.0.1).

While I'm in Windows (10) and the phone is on, it won't charge over USB. If I turn off the phone it charges via USB. If I'm in post or the BIOS of my computer the phone charges via USB while on.

I tried the same with a Nexus 5 and it charges while in Windows as expected.

The mobo is an Asus Z170-A. I didn't see any USB power option in the BIOS.

I've updated to the latest version

Comment: @beeshyams The 6P is Type C, this is the 6 it's just a micros USB port. I'm on Marshmallow 6.0.1.